# login logout php setting variable

Tags: php

Any help over here?

```
    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <?php
        echo ''.(!isset($_SESSION['username']) ? '<li><a href="index.php?page=$pgname"><?=ucfirst($pgname)?></a></li>' : 'b');
       $pgname="login";
       //$pg = "logout";
       ?>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=admin">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=update">Update</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=$pgname"><?=ucfirst($pgname)?></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=$pgname"><?=ucfirst($pgname)?></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I want when the user is already logged in to print only the logout menu button, and otherwise when is logout, only the log in to be appeared on the menu. how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your piece of code like below code,

```
<?php
$pagename =  !empty($_SESSION['username']) ? 'login' : 'logout';
?>
```

**Remove last two lines & change to this**

```
<li><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $pagename;?>"><?php echo ucfirst($pagename)?></a></li>
```

> Note: **dont forget to start session on very first line if your current code does not getting called by any other file**

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']){
        $pgname="login";
    }else{
        $pgname="logout";
    }
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=$pgname'>".ucfirst($pgname)."</a></li>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?php
    $pgname =  (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) ? 'login' : 'logout';
?>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=<?=$pgname?>"><?=ucfirst($pgname)?></a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=admin">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=update">Update</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=$pgname"><?=ucfirst($pgname)?></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=$pgname"><?=ucfirst($pgname)?></a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your PHP logic separate from your HTML. Build up the link string in PHP. Then lower in the page when you're outputting HTML, output the string

```
<?php
//make sure you've called start_session() already    
$pg = isset($_SESSION['username'])? 'login':'logout';
$link_html = '<li><a href="index.php?page='.$pg.'">'.ucfirst($pg).'</a></li>';
...
?>

<!-- then in html -->
<?= $link_html ?>
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```